# How to use another table as the login table instead of 'Users'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a project that has 2 tables, 1 for users details and one for login, but I want my login table to be 'webusers' instead of 'users' as Laravel uses 'users' as the default table for authentication.

I tried to change my model and auth.php but to no luck. Has anyone tried this before?

My Model:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $table = "webusers";
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

auth.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'webusers',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'webusers',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'webusers',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'webusers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'webusers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Comment: Why do you care about renaming the table? Why are you keeping the users general details separate to their login info? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: What do you mean by `login table`? That makes 0 sense

Comment: @ADyson I was using the users table as my login table till I realised that when i put the program on a server, the users table would serve another purpose so I want to make webusers that login table

Comment: @workservice the auth table, sorry, where all the users login details will be stored when they register or login

Comment: Ok so if I understood correctly, you want the users to be stored on `webusers` by using the model User.php ?

Comment: That doesn't appear to make much sense...why would the table suddenly be different just because you deploy it somewhere else? Are you saying there's already a table with that name in the server database, used by something else (e.g. another application)?

Comment: @ADyson Yes theres a table on the server with the name users, and that table can not be changed

Comment: So let me get this straight, it sounds like you're trying to deploy tables for a new application into a database which already contains tables to support something else? I can only assume so, otherwise your local database would surely have contained this users table already, and you would have met the problem before now. So...why are you doing that? It almost certainly makes a lot more sense for each application to have its own database. I smell an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) of some sort, here.

Comment: @ADyson No, No there is a misunderstanding, my mistake. So I am working on an application locally to be deployed on a server, now I am using a dummy database locally so it doesnt affect my live DB. however the users table on the live DB contains information thats not like the local DB. So when I host the app, its trying to read off that users table that isnt the the one having all my user info. If that makes sense?

Comment: So you mean you've changed the design of the users signficiantly from what is already live, to the extent that the existing PHP does not understand it?

Comment: It sounds like your solution is 2 different `.env` files for 2 different environments if you say that your local app is connecting to production DB.

Answer (score 0):

first change your model lets call it Admin like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable //extends authenticable instead of Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];
}
```

then go to `confi/auth.php` and change the provider method as shown below

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class, //change from User class to Admin
        ],
```

now everywhere instead of User model you need to call Admin models, the same logics can be used everywhere